# JQuery Slidedown function

Tags: jquery, image, slidedown

I am pretty new when it comes to using JQuery. I know that what I want to do is very basic.

Basically, I need to create a "caption" box that slides down when an image is clicked.

**User** clicks the image, and a tiny caption box slides out the bottom to describe to him/her what he has just clicked.

I have created a tiny image to further clarify what I need to do.

[image]

Comment: Like this http://www.catchmyfame.com/jquery/dropcaptions/?

Comment: Yes, but on the image CLICK, not mouseover - Is that an easy change?

Comment: It should be. Just try changing the plugin's use of mouseover or hover to click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check TheNewBoston is a channel on youtube telling you how to use jQuery even from scratch.

Here is an example. I think this could help you.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.box-img').click(function() {
        $('.box-caption').slideDown('slow');
    });

});
```

CSS:

```
.box-img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: thin solid gray;
    position: relative;
}

.box-caption {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-color: #d4d4d4;
    display: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="box-img">
    my image

    <div class="box-caption">my caption</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the really going through that.

Exactly what I needed.

Comment: Sorry, so what exactly do I need to change in this example to get my desired result? I understand the HTML/CSS - but does the Java stuff at the top need to be changed? (eg. "document", "box-img", "box-caption")

Comment: Nevermind, I got that understood. Its working nicely.

Could you tell me how to make it so when its clicked again, It hides the caption? Also, checking out TheNewBoston as we speak! Thanks!

Comment: nop, you don't have to change the document ready. Here is a link to understand better: 
http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Introducing_$(document).ready()

Comment: Yes! check theNewBoston is a good start. To do the hide caption you should make a conditional asking is the 'caption' is hidden with 'mycaption:hidden'.

Comment: Really appriciate all your help, I got this working - but for some reason it slides up when clicked? 
I click the Image and the box comes from the bottom of the image upwards and stops.

Comment: Like this?

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.box-img').click(function () {
        if ($("box-image").is(":hidden")) {
            $('.box-caption').slideDown('slow');
        } else {
            $("box-caption").hide();

        });

Comment: Actually, still want to know why this slides up from the bottom of the image, instead of the bottom of the image downwards

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/  here you can see some samples, it is pretty easy really:

```
$('#ImageID').click(function() {
    $('#captionboxID').slideDown('slow');
});
```